Can 3 power supplies safely share common ground?
I have a project with a DC motor @ 24V, an actuator @ 12V and an Arduino @ 5V. The motor and the actuator may draw several amps. The Arduino doesn't drive the motor nor the actuator, nor is it connected to them. I have 12V, 24V and 5V power supplies (the bigger 12V & 24V ones are like the one linked below). Can I safely connect the common/black outputs of all the supplies (green line), to eliminate extra wires?
Power supply


Short answer: yes

What is the reason you want to tie these grounds together? Unless there's a technical reason to have a common ground, It's almost always best to keep the circuits separate (no conducted interference, common-mode coupling, ect.).

Can you identify which wires you intend to eliminate?

@MicrocontrollerEnjoyer Thanks.

You can, with caveats. With high current and especially high \$\mathrm dI/\mathrm dt\$ loads like a motor, you want to be cognizant of what return currents are going where and by what path. In addition to the interference that @MOSFET mentions, there's also the possibility of ground bounce, where high return currents in insufficiently-sized conductors can cause ground terminals to rise in potential relative to their supply and signal voltages, which could cause problems.
An example would be if you had the motor and Arduino grounds tied together at their respective supplies and a long line connecting this common ground to the devices at the other end. Star grounding configurations are a common (no pun intended) way to prevent this; whether or not it would be appropriate for your application is unknown with the information we have so far. I mention this only because you are talking about reducing wiring.

If the loads are relatively small then go ahead and make all the grounds common at the power supply side and you can use a single wire like you want to do however be aware that this can sometimes cause issues especially if you have large currents and voltage sensitive devices.
To understand why you need to look at the wire as a small valued impedance.  To make it simpler just think of it as a small resistor.  When there is current flowing through this resistor (wire), a voltage will develop across it according to ohms law (V=IR).  So if the motor is drawing a large current, then the actuator will see its voltage change by that amount.  It is up to you to determine if this voltage noise is acceptable or not.
This is the same phenomenon that you get at home when the lights dim momentarily when the AC turns on.
Of course if you have AC currents flowing you also need to consider inductance, but the concept remain the same.
To learn more about this, you can look up common impedance coupling.

OP clearly states "The Arduino doesn't drive the motor nor the actuator, nor is it connected to them"
